# Switch генерирует событие изменения состояния

Tags: android, android-data-binding, android-switch

Связываю объект с макетом через databinding, для того, чтобы выставить начальные значения свитчей в макете, соответственно, не хочу чтобы вызывалось событие изменения при инициализации, поэтому вешаю слушатели изменения состояния свитча после привязки, но событие изменения все равно вызывается, что я делаю не так?

```
  override fun initView(buo: Buo) {

        mBinding.buo = buo

        mBinding.switchHandle.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            mPresenter.switchHandleChange(isChecked)
        }

        mBinding.switchPhaseA.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            mPresenter.switchPhaseA(isChecked)
        }

        mBinding.switchPhaseB.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            mPresenter.switchPhaseB(isChecked)
        }

        mBinding.switchPhaseC.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            mPresenter.switchPhaseC(isChecked)
        }

        mBinding.switchPhaseAbc.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            mPresenter.switchPhaseABC(isChecked)
        }
    }
```

Отрывок из макета

```
 <Switch
       android:id="@+id/switch_handle"             
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
       android:checked="@{ buo.modeStatus }"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Запустите `initView` в `onStart()` а

```
mBinding.switchHandle.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            mPresenter.switchHandleChange(isChecked)
        }
```

в `onCreate(...)`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, не совсем понял почему Вы советуете выполнить initView позже установления слушателей, поместил initView в onCreateView(), а инициализацию слушателей в onStart(), результат оказался без изменений.

Comment: Извините перепутал, наооборот

Comment: Ничего страшного, решил проблему тем, что отказался от байндинга, если бы вы могли подсказать, почему он себя так непонятно ведет, то был бы очень благодарен.

Comment: Отказаться это не решения, дело в том что байндинг происходит после setOnCheckedChangeListener, и тем самым во время бандитка меняется состояние вашего checkbox и сообщает вам, нужно переставить банкинг в другое место чтобы он происходил до setOnCheckedChangeListener

Comment: Я бы решил это проблему двумя тремя способами, 1) Банкинг дело бы в LiveData 2) вместо setOnCheckedChangeListener использовал onClickListener или установил setOnCheckedChangeListener в Бандунге самым последним